# How to use Limit and Offset with alias, where alias is an incrementing serial number?

Tags: mysql

I am using an alias as a ranking number that increments by +1 for each row. I have 1000+ rows. When using `limit 100 offset 0`, alias shows correctly `1-100`, but when `limit 200 offset 100`, I am expecting alias to show as `101,102,....200`, but it starts from 1 and rows data actually is from `101 - 200`.

**I want the alias to increment with the Limit and Offset.**

```
SELECT (@a := @a + 1)asset_rank,
totalSupply,
lastPriceUSD,
marketCap
CAST(volume_24h AS DECIMAL(65, 0)) AS volume24h,
(CASE
WHEN lastPriceUSD > 1 THEN CONCAT('$', FORMAT(lastPriceUSD, 2))
WHEN lastPriceUSD < 1 THEN CONCAT('$', FORMAT(lastPriceUSD, 4))
END) as USDPrice
FROM assetList,
(SELECT @a := 0  ) AS a
WHERE volume_24h > 0 AND isActive = 'yes'
ORDER BY marketCap DESC
limit 200 offset 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change your offset you need to change the initialisation of `@a` to match, so for `offset 100` you would use

```
(SELECT @a := 100  ) AS a
```

instead of

```
(SELECT @a := 0  ) AS a
```